# Does GitHub publish the CodeQL ruleset?

Tags: security, github, owasp, codeql

I'd like to cross-check the vulnerabilities covered by GitHub's CodeQL service and *[OWASP Top Ten Web Application Security Risks](https://owasp.org/www-project-top-ten/)* so that I know where the gaps are.

I can't find a list of vulnerabilities covered by CodeQL. Does GitHub publish the list of rules?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The source code of the CodeQL queries is available in the [GitHub repository](https://github.com/github/codeql). The documentation also lists the existing queries:

- [CodeQL query help](https://codeql.github.com/codeql-query-help/)
- [CodeQL CWE coverage](https://codeql.github.com/codeql-query-help/codeql-cwe-coverage/)

However, which queries (or rather query suites) are run as part of GitHub workflows depends on the configuration of the workflow.